# date range checking in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, c#-4.0, compare

How to find if a date in the input is within a specific daterange (let's say for example wihtin last 7 days, meaning I will say -7). If it is within last 7 days, do something, else do something else.

I currently could do upto this, but I don't know how to change this further to meet what I want.

```
string a = "-1"; // These are values that are configurable based on which date is checked. Yesterday means, -1 for example. 
string b = "-15"; // -15 means within last 15 days.

DateTime d = input;
DateTime e = d.AddDays(int.Parse(a));
if (d is between datetime.now and e)
{
   //do something
} 
else do something
```

Comment: There is no `between` type operation in C#. You'll need to do `d >= lowerLimit && d <= upperLimit` (replace with `<` and `>` depending if range is  exclusive rather than inclusive).

Comment: @Richard: Richard, mate, I know that. I wrote an algorithm and want to know how to translate that into C# lol. I will give you thumbsup for your comment :D :D :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use less than(<) and greater than(>) operator basicly.

I mean you should change your if conditionlike:

```
if (d >= e && d <= DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: I think yours is very redeable to me, hope it dont throw any null ref exception or any sort? Is it robust always in all scenario?

Comment: you need to be sure that your string a, which you wait to be parseable to integer, has acceptable value. If it's an input from user, you should consider to use int.TryParse method.

Comment: Mate, its not input from user, its from the database. It can however have null values (At worst case scenario as the column is nullable and we put null if there is no value). What will happen in that case? Exception or something good?

Comment: d is the only input

Comment: If you try to access a variable with null value, you'll get ArgumentNullException. you should decide what to do in that case.

Comment: what to do in that case pls

Answer (score 2):

First of all, use meaningful names instead of `a` and `b`, secondly: use proper data types (you don't use `b` at all):

```
int dayOffset = -1;
int lowerBound = -15;

var currentDate = DateTime.Now;

if(input >= currentDate.AddDays(dayOffset) && input <= currentDate)
{ // do smoething }
```

Using your names:

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now;

if(input >= currentDate.AddDays(a) && input <= currentDate)
{ // do smoething }
```

Comment: Mate, your answer is extremely confusing to me not redeable. Well, I use proper microsoft standard naming convention in project, here I gave for example and easy redeabilty. I am layman I cant understand offset or lowerbound etc....You can take only one string. Secondly, coming to datatype, its the business rule, we ought to have multiple data into that column so not possible to have it as int.

Comment: ok thanks a lot, but I am afraid it was complex for me to understand at first place unless U give attention to detail (Spend a more effort to understand)

Comment: I guess currentDate.AddDays() part in if statement looks confusing for @Learner

Comment: I just saw that, yes. Also he says its as per my variables, its not. You (Ozan Topal) wrote as per my variable, so eye catching. Thanks anyway both of you. Ozan, I have a question for you below, please clarify

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this to compare `Date` portion without `Time`

```
string a = "-1"; // These are values that are configurable based on which date is checked. Yesterday means, -1 for example. 
string b = "-15"; // -15 means within last 15 days.
DateTime d = new DateTime();
DateTime e = d.AddDays(int.Parse(a));
if (DateTime.Now.Date >= d.Date && e.Date <= d.Date)
{

}
```

Comment: Thaqnk you ebraheem. Why do you use Date component? Why not without that?

Comment: to compare date only without time